# Firebase child_added won't retrieve data when a lot of children added in a short time

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a server written in Node.js which listens to a certain node for updates (child_added) and if there are any, it creates another child in another node based on the information retrieved with "child_added". I have written a script to test the capacity of the server by adding, lets say 500 children in a "for loop" (in a really short time). The problem is that, the server stops retrieving data after adding around 340 children. Why this happens? Is it maybe because I'm using a "free plan" on Firebase? Or maybe the server goes out capacity because of too much threads? Firebase seems to handle every detail by itself so I don't know if I should manually close the threads/processes after I'm done with them.

The server code:

```
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot){

     createGame(snapshot.val());

}

function createGame(..){
     ..
     ..
     ref2.push().set(..);
     ..
     ..
}
```

The test code:

```
for(var i=0; i<TEST_CAPACITY; i++){
     ref.push().set(...);
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing the code, post the [**minimal** code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've edited my question.

Comment: I just ran a tight loop adding 5000 items without any problems. If you're having problems, you might want to enable debug logging with `firebase.database.enableLogging(true);` to see if you get any problems. Mine all go through with `p:0: from server: {"r":5002,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}
p:0: p response {"s":"ok","d":""}`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It turned out that, it was about my horrible internet connection. We also tested in another computer (another city) and encountered the same problem so I thought it was about the limits of the free plan. I've done the same test yesterday and today, it worked well! I think we should use a proper Node.js hosting to keep the server.